# Laravel HasManyThrough not working

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want get all merchant users for a specific merchant. Here is my setup;

```
merchant
- id

merchant_user_permission
- merchant_id (equal to merchant.id)
- user_id (equal to merchant_user.id)

merchant_user
- id
```

In my code I have tried:

```
class Merchant extends Model
{
    public function merchant_users()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(MerchantUser::class, MerchantUserPermission::class, 'user_id');
    }
}
```

But the resulting sql is invalid.

> string(374) "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'merchant_user.merchant_user_permission_id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `merchant_user` inner join `merchant_user_permission` on `merchant_user_permission`.`id` = `merchant_user`.`merchant_user_permission_id` where `merchant_user_permission`.`user_id` = 123-3456-7789-qwerty)"

Here is a working sql example:

```
SELECT mu.`id`, mu.`email`
FROM `merchant` m
LEFT JOIN `merchant_user_permission` mup ON m.id = mup.merchant_id
LEFT JOIN `merchant_user` mu ON mu.id = mup.user_id
WHERE mup.`merchant_id` = '123-3456-7789-qwerty'
```

How can replicate that using Eloquent 5.4?

Comment: You will have to use [joins](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#joins) to replicate this query.

Comment: @devk that's using the query builder, he wants to use the eloquent

Comment: try [belongsToMany](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) instead hasManyThrough

Comment: @ezw Relationships don't perform joins like this. They perform an additional query for the related model. You can't get this exact query with any relationship with eloquent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

Make many to many relationship

```
class Merchant extends Model
{
    public function merchant_users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\ MerchantUser', 'merchant_user_permission', 'merchant_id', 'merchant_user_id');
    }
}
```

then

```
$permissions = App\Merchant::find($merchant_id)->merchant_users()->get();
```

Comment: Works well. Thanks